# Jquery Gives Error with status 200 for Spring Jersey Json Example?

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jersey, jackson

Here is my resouce class:

```
@Path("/a")
public class SolrCloudResource {

 @GET
 @Path("/b")
 @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
 public DocCollection listClusterState() {
     ...      
 }
```

Here is my jquery code:

```
$.ajax({
        async : false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: getUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
            ...
        },
        error: function(data) {
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
            ...
        }
    });
```

However it goes into error function. When I look at console at Firebug I see:

```
error
Object { readyState=4, responseText="{"name":"collection1","...llection1","node_name":", status=200, more...}
```

I don't make a cross origin request. It happens only when I return application json from my resource class and I define dataType as json. If I do it just string it doesn't cause any problem. I think that jackson should work here automatically. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was related to format. JSON format was not valid and this was causing to go into error function.